# FilterEventHandler with custom parameters?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm interested in creating a new FilterEventHandler and associating it to a CollectionViewSource. All works fine, unless I want this handler to receive a parameter (let's say "price") in order to help with the filtering process.

However, when I try to put this extra-parameter, I'm getting a message which tells me that no overload matches the FilterEventHandler delegate signature (that's true, btw :p).

How can I achieve what I want? Is it possible? Or ... should I need to use a global variable instead a parameter in order to store that value and use it from the filtering method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new object that contains all the parameters you require.e.g

> public FilterData { decimal Price {get;set;} int Quantity{get;set;} }

Set this object to the FilterEventArgs Item property.

Now when this event is raised, check that the Item property is of FilterData type. If so, cast to FilterDate and voila! You now have access to a Quantity, Price and whatever other properties you want to add.